# Python Tkinter Image saying 'no such file or directory'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I know many questions are out there on this but none of the solutions seem to have worked.
Here is my code:

```
image_1 = PhotoImage(file="AeolusPavillion_01"); image_1 = subsample(2)
backImg = Label(screen, image=image_1).place(x=50,y=50)
```

The error I get when this is run is
`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "AeolusPavillion_01": no such file or directory`

I have tried using `tk.PhotoImage()` and `os.path.` and using the actual path directory instead of the image name too but none of these have fixed it. e.g. `c:/users/...`
The image file is within the same folder as the python file and I made sure it was a .png file too as I heard JPEGs don't work in tkinter.

Has anyone got any solutions to what I could try next?

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. There is no file in the current working directory lliterally named `AeolusPavillion_01`. Maybe you left off the suffix, maybe you're assuming the image file is relative to the script instead of the working directory. Maybe the `0` (zero) should be an `O` (oh). Maybe there is some other typo. The bottom line is that you're giving tkinter a bad filename.

Comment: I tried some of my older files too which I used images in and none of those seem to be working either. So I don't think its the file name. Its like Visual Studio Code/python/tkinter aren't picking up any of my files....

Comment: Python absolutely will not give this error unless it literally can't find the file. Are you aware that relative filenames are relative to the current working directory, which may not be the same as the directory that your script is in? If you're getting a "no such file" error, you can assume that the error is telling the literal truth.

Comment: How do I make it find my files then? you got any ideas :)

Comment: Do you understand the concept of current working directory, and how it may not be the same as the directory that the script is in? Does the file actually have a suffix like .png, but that suffix is hidden in explorer?

Comment: Did you try `PhotoImage(file="AeolusPavillion_01.png")`?

Comment: Yes .png has worked. Thanks everyone for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try doing

```
image_1 = PhotoImage(file="AeolusPavillion_01.jpg"); image_1 = subsample(2)
backImg = Label(screen, image=image_1).place(x=50,y=50)
```

or whatever file type it is